# Passing undefined value as argument to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, undefined

How can I `pass` or send undefined value as an argument to dictionary? Consider this scenario:

```
Dict = {(1,'a'): 2, (1,''): 1, (1,'c'): 1, (3,'1'): 3};


print Dict [(1, pass)];
```

I want to get list of entries the dictionary which has first argument as 1.

**Eg.**

```
Dict [(1, pass)]
```

I want it to return:

```
{(1,'a'): 2, (1,''): 5, (1,'c'): 7}
```

How it can be done?

Regards

Comment: Your problem begs for a nested dict of the form `{1: {'a': 2, '': 1, 'c': 1}, 3: {'1': 3}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pass anything other than the value you expect to be in the key, that is 1. You can construct a new `dict`, with the dictionary comprehension like this

```
my_dict = {(1,'a'): 2, (1,''): 1, (1,'c'): 1, (3,'1'): 3}
print {k: my_dict[k] for k in my_dict if 1 in k}
# {(1, 'c'): 1, (1, 'a'): 2, (1, ''): 1}
```

**Note:**  [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is a statement in Python, which cannot be used in place of values. Perhaps you meant [`None`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None).

**Edit:** If you know for sure that the value you are looking for will be in the first position always, you can do it like this (Thanks to @zhangxaochen :) )

```
print {k: my_dict[k] for k in my_dict if 1 == k[0]}
```

Comment: I think it makes more sense to use `if 1 == k[0]`

Comment: @zhangxaochen Thanks man :) Included that also in the answer.

Comment: Notice that you can also iterate over `key, value` pairs like: `{key: value for key, value in my_dict.iteritems() if key[0] == 1}`

Comment: @thefourtheye I am new to Python, so can you break down what this `{k: my_dict[k] for k in my_dict if 1 == k[0]}` means?

Comment: @UmerFarooq That is called dictionary comprehension, a way to create a dictionary. That statement has to be read like this `for k in my_dict`, iterate over the keys of the dictionary, and `if 1 == k[0]` then `k: my_dict[k]` add this to the dictionary being constructed. `my_dict[k]` will give the value corresponding to the key `k` in the dictionary.

Comment: @thefourtheye & what is the value of `k` in the begining? This is kind of weird compared to how C/C++,Java,C# or other languages work.

Comment: @UmerFarooq Indeed :) When we run a for loop over a dict, it returns all its keys. So, on each iteration, `k` will have the keys one by one.

Comment: @thefourtheye so in the begining, `k` will have the very first value of dict i-e; `(1,'a'):2`. Am I right?

Comment: @UmerFarooq In dictionaries we cannot guarantee the order, so it could be any of the keys. And just the keys, so `k` could be any of `(1,'a'), (1,''), (1,'c'), (3,'1')`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to do that:

```
def filterFirst(a, Dict):
  return {k: Dict[k] for k in Dict if k[0] == a}
```

You can also create a filter that filters on any index of the key-tuples:

```
def filterDictionary(a, Dict, index):
  return {k: Dict[k] for k in Dict if k[index] == a}
```

Make sure that there are only tuples in the dictionary as keys.